# When is the cleanup function triggered when using useEffect hook with dependencies?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using a useEffect to show a UI Loading... but only after 250ms.
It works ... but I really don't understand why and specially how and when useEffect invokes the returned function (that clears the timeout).

Well ... I'm not sure that's work perfectly. Sometimes the "Loading ..." message should appear but it's not.

```
 const [loadingAfterShortTime, setLoadingAfterShortTime] = useState(false);

 useEffect(() => {
  setLoadingAfterShortTime(bool => false);
  if (myDepandanceToTrigTheLoadingWord === true) {
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      setLoadingAfterShortTime(bool => true);
    }, 250);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(id);
    };
  }
}, [myDepandanceToTrigTheLoadingWord]);
```

Comment: Hey, I just reworded your title to be in the form of a question.  Feel free to modify it if you don't think I did a good job preserving the intent of the original question.

Comment: The cleanup function is called whenever the dependencies change, and when the component is unmounted.

Comment: So ... outside the case where the component is unmounted, all stuff include into the useEffect function, including the return statement, is call at every dependencie change ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The explanation provided by @Powell Ye is good however there a bit of erroneous information specifically when speaking about re-renders (e.g. when props change)

consider some simple component with the following

```
    useEffect( () => {
        console.log('Effect is applied')
        //some logic
        return () => {
            console.log('cleaning up')
            //cleanup logic
        }
    })
    return (<>
        {console.log('rendering...')}
     </>)
```

say the props passed in changes you might think it goes as such

1. 'cleaning up'
2. **new props**
3. 'rendering...'
4. 'Effect is applied'

However, the following actually occurs

1. **new props**
2. 'rendering...'
3. 'cleaning up'
4. 'Effect is applied'

That is, the clean up function runs **AFTER** the new render/painting but **BEFORE** the 'new' effects are applied, the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect) can be a bit ambigious about this

> the previous effect is cleaned up before executing the next effect

This is done for performance reasons => so that rendering is not delayed ( it can be frustrating at times for me too )

Comment: Was there a real need to create another answer? Thanks for pointing out an inconsistency, however your behaviour appears to be somewhat rude as you could have suggested an improvement to my already comprehensive explanation.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way but the answer you provided has erroneous data, in fact, that specific bit about updates has caused me quite a lot of wasted hours, I just thought it should be made clear so that no one else had to go through what I did

Answer (score 1):

Here's an outline of the timings involved:

- `useEffect` is called on the initial render and whenever any of the values it depends on change. In general, it fires after the rendering is completed. If you think of it in terms of a class-based component, equivalent would be `componentDidMount` method.
- The function returned from within `useEffect` is invoked before the component is removed from the UI or is about to re-render (to avoid memory leaks). Previous effect is always cleaned up before performing the next effect. It's guaranteed to run before any new renders. Equivalent would be `componentWillUnmount`.

#### Example

Let's assume that there is a `useEffect` with few dependencies made of props (which are passed to our component) + a cleanup function. On the first render, the following would happen:

- Once the component is mounted, code inside effect's body will run;
- Cleanup function stays put, ready to run before the component re-renders / is removed from the screen.

Now let's imagine something triggers a re-render. Since it's listed as something `useEffect` depends on, the effect will be re-executed as following:

- Cleanup function executes after rendering is completed;
- Right after that, code inside effect's body will run;
- New cleanup function is created, again, ready to execute after the component re-renders / or before it's removed from the screen.

Comment: If my component is not remove (only the deps change). Does the function returned from within `useEffect` is systematically invoked when the dependencies changes ? And if so, when exactly, compared to the `render` ?

Comment: I've added an example to my answer describing the cycle. Hopefully it's clear!

Comment: Marvelous! Merci beaucoup ... Where did you learn that, please ?

Comment: De rien!  Glad I was able to help. To answer your question: mostly official docs, and hands-on trial of course.

Answer (score 0):

As per the react documentation,

[Cleaning up an effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect)

> The clean-up function runs before the component is removed from the UI
>   to prevent memory leaks. Additionally, if a component renders multiple times (as they typically do), the previous effect is cleaned up before executing the next effect.

[Timing of effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#timing-of-effects)

> React will always flush a previous render’s effects before starting a
>   new update.

As per my understanding from both the quotes, cleanup runs after the effect is applied and before the component is *unmounted* (removed from UI).