# Some questions about the cleanUp of useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am learning react native and I am using react hooks now. I am happy, about that, but I am struggling a little bit with the clean up of the useEffect. 
What I get is, that I use this to clean up the component. For instance, I can reset a timer. But would I also use a clean up for a data array?

For instance, I am fetching data in the useEffect and then when I dismount I am resetting the data array back to null? I also see a lot of times ( in some example) the useEffect like that:

```
useEffect(() => {
doSomething, fetchData;

return => { console.log("clean up")}
},[]);
```

Since this is just a console.log, am I right, that nothing is happening here and this is just a placeholder in the example?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: When a react element is unmounted, all the state is destroyed so you dont have to reset anything manually. Cleanup function is mainly used to avoid updating a state in an already unmounted element. For example closing a websocket connection or ignoring a request that taked too long and finishes when the component already disappeared in the UI

Comment: While you're on this topic look at what happens when you return a cleanup function from a useEffect with a dependency list. It can be a little bit confusing but is very important and in my experience most react developers have no idea that it even exists. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55148322/when-is-the-cleanup-function-triggered-when-using-useeffect-hook-with-dependenci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanup function is there is clean up any running subscription, event listeners, timers, open web-socket connections that can still be running even after the component unmounts.

For example

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(() => {console.log("hello")},1000)
}, [])
```

In the case above we `console.log` 'hello' in an interval of 1s. If we do not provide a cleanup function to clear the interval the interval would be running even after the component unmounts, causing memory leaks in the application. Same thing can happen with timers, opened web-socket connections.

That is why clean up function needs to provided to close any long running task or opened resources to close them when the component unmounts.

**To fix the interval situation**

```js
useEffect(() => {
  let interval = setInterval(() => {console.log("hello")}, 1000)

  return () => {
    clearInterval(interval) // clear the interval in the returning function
  }
}, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `useEffect` returns function which will be called on component unmount. So this is the right place for all clean up, unsubscribe, release and etc. operations.